# How to excute SQL Queries from '.sql' file into MySQL database using NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mysql-workbench

###### Stack and Enviroment

- I am using `NodeJS` for back-end server and `MySQL` for storing the database.
- I am using `MySQL Workbench` to design the database model.
- with MySQL Workbench I can generate a '.sql' script that contains all the queries of my database model.

**How to execute the generated '.sql' script into MySQL database using NodeJS server ?**

- I have already tried using the `SQLite package` following this online tutorial [Running SQL Queries from a ‘.sql’ file in NodeJS (SQLite)](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/running-sql-queries-from-an-sql-file-in-a-nodejs-app-sqlite-a927f0e8a545)
  , but unfortunately no luck and it keeps throwing errors.

Would really appreciate any suggestion, thanks for your help :)

`generated-script.sql`

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema db_test
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema db_test
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `db_test` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `db_test` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `assessment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assessment` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `patient_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `assessment_type` INT NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` DATE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `assessment_patient_idx` (`patient_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `assessment_type_idx` (`assessment_type` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `assessment_patient`
    FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`)
    REFERENCES `patient` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `assessment_type`
    FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_type`)
    REFERENCES `assessment_type` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `assessment_type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assessment_type` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `label` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `images`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `assessment_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `assessment_image_idx` (`assessment_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `assessment_image`
    FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_id`)
    REFERENCES `assessment` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `patient`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `patient` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `user_notes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_notes` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `assessment_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `content` VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `user_note_assessment_idx` (`assessment_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `user_note_user_idx` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `user_note_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `assessment_type` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_note_assessment`
    FOREIGN KEY (`assessment_id`)
    REFERENCES `assessment` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `users_patients`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_patients` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `patient_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `users_patients_patient_idx` (`patient_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `users_patients_user_idx` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `users_patients_patient`
    FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`)
    REFERENCES `patient` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `users_patients_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is : since you have multiple table creation scripts, best would be if you separate every table creation script into files, in this way you have full modularity over the things you want to achieve. However ...

You can read from a file and execute a query aginst it:

```
const generatedScript = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../generated-script.sql')).toString();
const query = await db.query(generatedScript,  (err, result) => {
    if (err){
         throw err;
    }else{
        res.send("Query run successfully");
    }
```

The db config file could look something like this:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"-your host here -",
    user:"-your user here-",
    password:"-your password here-",
    database:"-your database here-"
});
```